# OpenLayers2 load local GML

Tags: openlayers-2, gml

I'm trying to load a simple GML file with `OpenLayers`, but it doesn't load.

Pretty sure it's a simple issue, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
var meu = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("States", {
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
    url: "teste.GML",
    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GML()
    }),
    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
 });

 map.addLayer(meu)
```

Tried Firefox and Safari in Mac OS and Firefox in Linux

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to load a file that is stored in the file system of your computer, the short answer is that you cannot. From the Wikipedia:

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the web. Browser authors contain this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run in a sandbox in which they can only perform web-related actions, not general-purpose programming tasks like creating files. Second, scripts are constrained by the same origin policy: scripts from one web site do not have access to information such as usernames, passwords, or cookies sent to another site. Most JavaScript-related security bugs are breaches of either the same origin policy or the sandbox. (http://goo.gl/iqW7n)